# Horizontal Clustering using HazelCast

Tags: java, distributed-computing, hazelcast

```
    I am using hazelCast-3.0 jars . I am able to create vertical cluster(on the same System where only port no. differ from one server to other Ip remains the same.) and its working  pretty good.But i want to create horizontal cluster(where i can use any ip address along with any port no. depending on the configuration). If this is possible in hazelCast then please share how. i went through several links like http://www.hazelcast.com/docs/1.9.4/manual/multi_html/ch11.html
    if this link is useful the suggest me how. I made only change to hazelcast.xml.
    <tcp-ip enabled="true">
                    <hostname>172.22.65.111</hostname>
                    <hostname>172.22.68.19</hostname>
                    <interface>172.22.*.*</interface>               
                </tcp-ip>
```

On both the system same jar file are being used.It i create a map name "xyz" and store some value to it .Then it should be available to other system with same map name "xyz".
    here is the code that I am using on my system 
    clientConfig.addAddress("172.22.65.111:5701");
                System.out.println("p2");
                HazelcastInstance client = HazelcastClient
                        .newHazelcastClient(clientConfig);

```
            IMap<Integer, String> map = client.getMap("m");
            map.put(1,"ram");
```

Same code is on the second system also except ip and port. And insteed of put i am trying to get on the other system.

Comment: You might get help after providing more information. What error do you get, what configuration do you use, how do you set up cluster nodes? Provide code!

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve or what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

your link refers to an outdated Version of the Manual.
If you follow the getting started guide at

http://www.hazelcast.com/docs/3.0/manual/single_html/#GettingStarted

you should be able to form a horizontal cluster by starting the sample code on two separate machines.

The current hazelcast distribution also contains a bin folder with sample applications.

Comment: After extracting the jar i got the bin folder but in that where is the sample applications.? I mean no sample application is there.

Comment: There is a commandline toy application. You can start it using 'start.sh' or 'start.bat'. I often use if when I do demo's.

Answer (score 0):

I find a new in memory grid based on hazelcast 3.0 clone-griddatamaster.(griddatamaster.wordpress.com) They claim they will provide enterprise class future like security,management console...and some cool futures from gigaspace and oracle coherence

griddatamaster.wordpress.com

Comment: Doesn't look that a lot of activity is going on.

Comment: Maybe it isn't easy to build a Coherence clone in a few months? ;-)